# Docker-compose cannot open self

Tags: docker

I am trying to install docker-compose on my computer (Ubuntu), after several failed attempts using curl,wget, and apt, I decided to download it directory from the repository and move it to usr/local/bin/docker-compose.

However, I keep getting the error `Cannot open self /usr/local/bin/docker-compose or archive /usr/local/bin/docker-compose.pkg`

I have tried several approaches:
- reinstallation
- changing of file permissions
- installing with wget, curl, and apt, and it is not working.

Answer (score 7):

Seeing the same issue and found the solution from [this page](https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/issues/1323), by use following instead:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > ~/docker-compose
chmod +x ~/docker-compose
sudo mv ~/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose run test
```

In my original case which cannot reproduce at the later time, I cannot even use `sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` to remove the original downloaded docker-compose file.  Finally I used `sudo lsattr /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`, then `sudo chattr -a /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` to clear the attributes that blocked the removal.

Comment: But why does this happen in the first place? Can I be sure it won't repeat now?

Answer (score 2):

As you did not give details on your "several failed attempts", I can only guess that you did not follow the right instructions.

There exists an issue from 2015 on [github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1135) on the same problem. From that issue, it seems that the way how to solve it is to install it exactly like the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) says:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

(Please look in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) for the current version number)

Same for docker itself, use the [official installation documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) and not the package provided from Ubuntu, it is usually outdatet.

Comment: Thank you @pLumo I started with the documentation and what you just posted here is exactly what I started with. I also listed the failed attempts - I tried to use curl as used in the documentation, then I tried to use wget, then I tried installing with apt, then I downloaded the file directly from their official repository and moved it to /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

This issue continues existing, at least in Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed docker-compose using curl and it works fine, but after some time, I don't know how the executable is modified (I've checked it comparing the md5sum of `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` just after downloading it and after it failed and they were different).

I've set the immutable bit of the executable using chattr:

```
chattr +i /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

and, for the moment, it seems to work.